# Moving cursor to first entry box pyqt5

Tags: python, pyqt5

I have a layout working with different number of entry boxes.

On return keypress event i am taking the values from all entry boxes and resetting the values.
After that the cursor is place at Last entry box only. How do i move the cursor to first entry box.

Used some other example from web here.

````
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator,QDoubleValidator,QFont
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
import sys

class lineEditDemo(QWidget):
        def __init__(self,parent=None):
                super().__init__(parent)
                self.e1 = QLineEdit()
                self.e1.setValidator(QIntValidator())
                self.e1.setMaxLength(4)
                self.e1.setAlignment(Qt.AlignRight)
                self.e1.setFont(QFont("Arial",20))

                self.e2 = QLineEdit()
                self.e2.setValidator(QDoubleValidator(0.99,99.99,3))
                self.e3 = QLineEdit()
                self.e3.setInputMask("+99_9999_999999")

                self.e4 = QLineEdit()
                self.e4.textChanged.connect(self.textchanged)

                self.e5 = QLineEdit()
                self.e5.setEchoMode(QLineEdit.Password)

                self.e6 = QLineEdit("Hello PyQt5")
                self.e6.setReadOnly(True)
                self.e5.editingFinished.connect(self.enterPress)

                self.flo = QFormLayout()
                self.flo.addRow("integer validator",self.e1)
                self.flo.addRow("Double validator",self.e2)
                self.flo.addRow("Input Mask",self.e3)
                self.flo.addRow("Text changed",self.e4)
                self.flo.addRow("Password",self.e5)
                self.flo.addRow("Read Only",self.e6)

                self.setLayout(self.flo)
                self.setWindowTitle("QLineEdit Example")

        def textchanged(self,text):
                print("Changed: " + text)

        def enterPress(self):
                print("Enter pressed")
        def keyPressEvent(self, e):
            if e.key() in [Qt.Key_Return, Qt.Key_Enter]:
                self.e1.clear()
                self.e2.clear()
                self.e3.clear()
                self.e4.clear()
                self.e5.clear()




if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        win = lineEditDemo()
        win.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec_())```

When return key is pressed the cursor is at password feild. I want it to be at integer validator.

Image for clarification
[after entering the values][1]

After enter key pressed password is highlighted 
[after return key pressed][2]



  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/bAvNn.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GN9WX.png
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`e1.setFocus()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFocus)  will give focus to `e1`, this is what you are looking for.

Another method is [`self.focusNextChild()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#focusNextChild) which will give focus to your first entry if your current cursor is in the last LineEdit (In other words, this method will give the focus to the first lineEdit only if the focus is already in the last one).

Do note: If your current cursor is not at the last lineedit when the return key is pressed the `focusNextChild` method will focus the next lineedit not the first one.